# What is cumulative generating function of this probability measure?

Tags: moment-generating-functions

I am trying to find what is CGF of this probability measure:

$$\mu=\alpha \delta_a+(1-\alpha) \delta_b$$

I found it difficult because when I tried to calculate Moment generating function, I didn't know what is $\mu(dx)$ (which is density function) but how it looks like :-(.

$$M_X(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp{(tx)} \mu(dx)$$

Comment: You mean the [*Cumulant* generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant).

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, sir!